# Form.Show or ShowMessage in the middle of function or procedure (Rad Studio 10 Seattle)

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I'm programming apps in Android with Delphi 10 Seattle and I found a problem...

I need to show a form and in this form I'll use a variable and set a value in it but after the form.show I'll continue using this variable to calculating it and get the value that I need.
The problem is that when the form shows the function continue before the user typing the value and press the confirm button on form and it's causing a problem with the results.

I already tried to use a inputbox but its cause the same problem.... It's interesting because in Delphi XE6 I had the same code and its work perfectly.
When I tried to search a solution I found a non-blocking that was implemented in Delphi XE7 forward.

Here a dumb example to be easily to understand what I wanted to do:

```
procedure TfrmForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  vExample, vResult: Integer
begin
  frmForm1.Edit1.Text := '';
  frmForm1.Show;
  if Length(form.Edit1.Text) = 0 then
    vExample := 0
  else
    vExample := StrToInt(form.Edit1.Text); 
  vResult := vExample * 5;
  ShowMessage('The result is ' + IntToStr(vResult));
end;
```

The problem is that always show 0 in the message and I don't know how to solve this problem...

Comment: Show returns immediately. You need to wait for the user to enter the value. On desktop platforms that would be a modal form, `ShowModal`. On mobile it's different: http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/xe5_anonymous_showmodal_android.html

Comment: This is Android FMX specific. Use Anonymous method. Try http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/What's_New_in_Delphi_and_C++Builder_XE7#Dialog_Box_Methods_Support_Anonymous_Methods_to_Handle_Their_Closing